# Is adding a single tag enough to constitute a meaningful edit?

Tags: discussion, editing

Just now, it appears that the Suggested Edits review queue is full to the brim with a single user adding the [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag to a lot of questions while leaving the content otherwise untouched.

I was tempted to simply outright reject these edits, but I am really not sure about whether this would be appropriate.

*Should these kinds of edits be rejected? Should they be discouraged, but accepted? Or am I in the wrong here and are these edits fine?*

Comment: There should be some feedback mechanism for the editors to realize that huge batches of edits might irritate or overwhelm the reviewers.  This has happened before -- and on other sites.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that adding a single, relevant tag is a meaningful edit. If it helps someone in the future to find a question that matches their search, or favourites, then, yes, it's a good edit.

Note that tag editing is "so important" that for higher-rep users (10K tools) "inline" tag-editing is optimized and is very easy to do. I regularly add tags using the tag-editing shortcuts. It's obviously a meaningful action, so why prevent lower-rep users from doing it?

On the other hand, adding non-relevant tags is obviously bad....

I reviewed a number of those single-tag [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) edits, and I approved them. If a person is willing to locate, fix, and suggest edits for them, then they deserve the +2 rep an approved edit will give them.

As it happens, while answering this meta-post, I also rejected a couple of tag-only edit suggestions where the [calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculator) tag was added incorrectly... it can go both ways.

Comment: Those tag edits were all by the same user.  Why was adding the calculator tags better than the performance tags?

Comment: The calc ones were worse. Those questions were not about calculators... but specific calculations

Answer (score 3):

I find the [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag is only justified if OP also provided some *benchmarks*. This is, we know how fast/slow the code is performing now.

Without such information it's pointless to try to optimize the code and so is the [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag meaningless.

Here two of those examples (where I removed the [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag again):

- [Query result as an HTML table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188936/query-result-as-an-html-table)
- [Cython class inheritance split into multiple .pyx and .pxd files [on hold]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183847/cython-class-inheritance-split-into-multiple-pyx-and-pxd-files)
- [Functions Giving Performance Issues](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14699/functions-giving-performance-issues) - here we don't even know if the code is working because it hangs the browser, who knows for what reason. This one should haven been closed for being borken and not decorated with the [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag.

Only a single question contained enough information to actually *qualify* for this tag:

- [Entity Framework Lazy loading performance comparison](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187387/entity-framework-lazy-loading-performance-comparison)

Comment: I agree, performance could apply to nearly every question that's not specifically on "style" - those of which will be reviewed on performance *anyway*.